# All 3 digit numbers are written into one long number $N=100101102...999$. Find $N \pmod {210}$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have no idea how to solve this, but I feel that $210=2\times3\times5\times7$ has something to do with the problem.

Comment: How are they written into one long number?

Comment: @kingW3 100101102...999

Comment: Try finding $N \pmod 2$, $N \pmod 3$, $N \pmod 5$, and $N \pmod 7$ using [divisibility rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) first.

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem: Finding the remainder mod $2\cdot 5$ should be easy (*its just the last digit*).  Finding the remainder mod $3$ should also be pretty straightforward (*think of the sum of the digits and how it relates*).  Now... finding the remainder mod $7$ is the only "unusual" one but only in that most people don't memorize the rule.  See [wikipedia's list of divisibility rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_7).  Combine all this information via [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: It certainly helps if you know that $1001=7\cdot11\cdot13$.

Comment: @kingW3: This is how the number is constructed. Consider a sequence of 3-digit numbers starting from 100 to 999: 100, 101, 102, 103, ..., 999. Now, concatenate them into a long string: N = 100101102103...999.

Comment: Having done the maths (or "math" if you're from the US) using JMoravitz' suggestion, the answer comes out to be $9$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's solve it explicitly based on JMoravitz's [suggestion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule).

For clarity, let's write out the number with spacing between 3 digits:

```
$$ N = 100 101 102 103 ... 998 999. $$
```

We claim the following:

$$ \begin{align} 
N &\equiv 1 \pmod 2, \quad (1) \\
N &\equiv 0 \pmod 3, \quad (2)  \\
N &\equiv 4 \pmod 5, \quad (3)  \\
N &\equiv 2 \pmod 7. \quad (4)  \\
\end{align}
$$

Once $(1)$ through $(4)$ are verified, it is straightforward to see that $N \equiv 9 \pmod 210$ where $210 = 2\cdot3 \cdot5\cdot7.$

Proof:

1. Note that $(1)$ and $(3)$ are obvious.
2. Prove (4) using the divisibility rule for 7 stated in the reference above:

> "Form the alternating sum of blocks of three from right to left"

Based on this rule:

$$\begin{align} 
   N &\equiv 999 - 998 + 997 - 996 + ... + 101 - 100, \pmod 7 \\
     &\equiv 1 + 1 + ... + 1, \pmod 7 \\
     &\equiv 450 = 7 \cdot 64 + 2, \pmod 7\\
     &\equiv 2 \pmod 7
\end{align} $$

3. Prove (3) using the divisibility rule for 3 stated in the reference above:

> "Subtract the quantity of the digits 2, 5, and 8 in the number from the quantity of the digits 1, 4, and 7 in the number. The result must be divisible by 3"

To count the digits correctly, we can rely on the pseudo code below to generate (print) the number N:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) { 
           print one three-digit block: i, j, k
        }
    }
}
```

Thus,

- There are 100 blocks having the same 'i' digit occur in the leftmost digit of the block: 10 'j' values times 10 'k' values. The total counts are 300 blocks with 'i' in the {1,4,7} group and 300 with 'i' in {2, 5, 8}.
- Similarly, there are 100 blocks having the same 'j' digit occur in the middle digit of the block: 10 'i' values times 10 'k' values.  The total counts are 300 in the {1,4,7} group and 300 in {2, 5, 8}.
- There are 100 blocks having the same 'k' digit occur in the rightmost digit of the block: 10 'i' values times 10 'j' values. 
  The total counts are 300 in the {1,4,7} group and 300 in {2, 5, 8}.

Thus, the total counts are 900 in the {1,4,7} group and 900 in {2, 5, 8}, which means:

$$ N \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

Answer (score 0):

Your number is $$\begin{align}
&100(1000)^{899}+101(1000)^{898}+\cdots+999(1000)^0\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{899}(999-n)(1000)^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{899}999(1000)^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{899}n(1000)^{n}\\
&=999\frac{1000^{900}-1}{1000-1}-\left.x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{899}x^{n}\right\rvert_{x=1000}\\
&=1000^{900}-1-\left.x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^{900}-1}{x-1}\right\rvert_{x=1000}\\
&=1000^{900}-1-\left.x\frac{(x-1)900x^{899}-(x^{900}-1)}{(x-1)^2}\right\rvert_{x=1000}\\
&=1000^{900}-1-1000\frac{(999)900(1000)^{899}-1000^{900}+1}{999^2}\\
&=1000^{900}-1-1000\frac{898100(1000)^{899}+1}{999^2}\\
&\equiv1-1-6\frac{0+1}{5^2}\mod{7}\\
&\equiv1/5^2\mod{7}\\
&\equiv3^2\mod{7}\\
&\equiv2\mod{7}\end{align}$$

Since the last digit is $9$, the number is $\equiv1$ modulo $2$ and $\equiv4$ modulo $5$.

Mod $3$, use the familiar digit summing rule. Each nonzero digit appears the same number of times, and $1+2+\cdots+9=45$ is divisible by $3$. So the sum of digits is divisible by $3$. So the number is $\equiv0$ modulo $3$. To finish, I didn't need the Chinese Remainder Theorem or anything like that, because it just sort of stands out that $9$ (a small number) satisfies all the conditions.

Comment: @TMM Thanks, reasoning amended.

Comment: Also, if the whole first derivation is just for the mod-7 part, you can simplify that a lot. Already in your first sum, you can replace 1000^n by (-1)^n, so that you have an alternating sum which can be solved much more easily than what you did now.

Comment: @TMM I like having the last expression for the number before the equivalencies begin. More than is needed for this purpose, but nice to know that the number can be expressed this way.

Comment: @TMM, for example, with that expression I could find the value mod $13$, mod $97$, or mod anything really except numbers not coprime to $999$.

Comment: Fair enough, but just to complete that argument: if you replace 1000^n by (-1)^n for mod-7, you get an alternating sum with 64*14 = 896 terms which cancel out, and only 4 terms (+2-1+0-6=2) to add manually.

Comment: Modulo 13, you can still replace 1000^n by (-1)^n ;-)